# My daily calorie intake

Tags: daily-caloric-intake

I calculated in [here][1] as it says 65kg male 175cm 29 yo, needs 3000 calories a day with following Activities every day. and I eat 500-1000 Calories everyday It means I lose 2000 Calories every day. 1 kg mean 7700 Calories(theoretically) so I need to lose 1kg every 4 days? Is that right?

1   Walking >> 5.5 km/hour 336 Calories Burnt

2   Sitting >> 720 minutes (12 hours)   1080 Calories Burnt

Comment: No. First off, that calculator (whichever, your link doesn't work) can only guess and is therefore not accurate. Second, your metabolism slows down if you eat less, so you will not really burn 2000kcal a day. In fact, if you're restricting calories this severely over an extended period of time you might damage your metabolism for a long time. Third, why would a 65kg male at 175cm need to lose weight?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you eat during one day? You may be eating more calories than you think....

Comment: omelette or some cheese at morning, diet cornflakes at lunch, and some fruit/nuts/yogurt at dinner.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla I have big stomach and I can feel some fat in there, I want to have a flat stomach. sorry for the link I lost it. what kind of damage are we talking about. any other suggestion?

Comment: @Mert: The kind of damage I'm talking about is 'metabolic damage', if you google it you should find some sources. Regarding the stomach, if you'd build some muscle the stomach would look smaller in comparison. It would also be much more healthy, as with such a rapid diet you will also lose muscle along with fat. In effect you'll get skinny fat, without improving your body fat percentage (and therefore looks).

Comment: You are not overweight. You are also far from being overweight. Why do you want to starve yourself and possibly damage your metabolism/immune system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of extreme weight loss program, as Larissa mentions, will have a negative impact on your body, and additionally will not be very sustainable. Based on your weight, and your description of your body, a far better path to achieve your goals will be starting a weightlifting program with a controlled diet.

While your main goal may be a flat stomach, you'll find that you see the greatest improvements with lifts that incorporate many muscles, such as deadlifts, squats, or bench press. I won't outline a weightlifting plan here since you didn't ask for one, but know that these sorts of exercises will lead you to the results you seek. If you definitely need to lose weight, then keep your diet at a normal level as you begin to exercise; the deficit created by working out will lead to lost weight. I'd recommend, however, with your weight, that the best strategy would be to eat a little bit more, add some protein to your diet, and focus on muscle gains, as these will bring you closer to the body I think you're looking for than pure weight loss will.

As a side note, you may have a normal amount of fat on your but just lack muscle underneath. [Web MD](http://www.webmd.com/diet/features/the-truth-about-belly-fat) offers a good summary of the role of stomach fat and explains how everyone has fat there to some degree. If you're in this situation, weightlifting is definitely the strategy to follow :)